# Web Accessibility - Screen Reader reads HTML element differently on mouse hover and on tabbing

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility, screen-readers

Screen Reader reads HTML element like a button differently on mouse over and on tab. When mouse over, it reads "My super button". While tabbing, it reads "Button my super button".

`<button aria-label="My super button">Super</button>`

How can I make them same as "My super button"?

I am using NVDA as a Screen Reader from https://www.nvaccess.org/

Comment: Not sure, but maybe because it's for blind people, so they need to know what is the type of element that is currently focused

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behaviour.

For someone who is using a screen reader in conjunction with a mouse it is assumed they have some vision (i.e. they are using a screen magnifier in conjunction with screen reader software) so the additional 'button' at the beginning is not necessary as they already visually know it is a button.

The idea of a screen reader is to be as succinct as possible (get the most information relayed in the shortest amount of time) so this behaviour is desirable.

For someone using a keyboard it is assumed that they are entirely reliant on the screen reader for information so indicating the fact you have a button selected is essential.

It does raise a good question on whether we should assume anything about how someone uses a screen reader but that is a whole other debate (i.e. what if someone has a cognitive disability and uses a screen reader to reassure them of what they are pressing).

There possibly could be a random setting someone that I can't find (I have looked just now) that allows the behaviour to be identical but I can't find it.

Comment: Good answer. Additionally, some screen readers have settings telling precisely which information has or hasn't  to be spoken in which use context. Jaws calls this verbosity. NVDA has much fewer options.

Comment: great additional tip there, i presume that is more of a 'power user' option once you know how certain elements present themselves you can remove unnecessary information?

Comment: i presume that is more of a 'power user' option once you know how certain elements present themselves you can remove unnecessary information? => Yes, exactly. Jaws offer 3 general levels of verbosity that you can further customize: beginner, intermediate and advanced. Beginner it talks a lot, advanced it says only what you only want to know and in very succinct terms. Quite few people customize these options.

Comment: Thanks, I have been using beginner for the last 3 years. Doh! I will have to try the other settings.